# Filtering by categories with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models Recipe and Category, they associated with has_and_belongs_to_many, now I need to filter recipes by categories, when user checks categories, I recive the array of checked categories ids and I create a scope for  filtering recipes like so:

```
scope :filter, -> (category_ids){ includes(:categories).where(categories: {id: category_ids}) if category_ids.present? }
```

and use this scope in recipes controller

```
Recipe.filter(params_index[:category_ids])
```

private

```
def params_index
  params.permit(category_ids: [])
end
```

The problem is that it returns recipe if any of categories id match with category_ids passed by user, for example if user checked breakfast and salad, my filter return all breakfasts and all salads, but I need only those recipes where contains both categories breakfast and salad. Can I do this with activerecord and how should look like query to db? I'm using rails 5 and postgresql. Hope for your help)

Comment: `group(:recipe_id).having("count(*) = ? ", category_ids.size)`?

Comment: I replaced :recipe _id to :id and it works fine.Thank you! very much!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `group` and `having`:

```
scope :filter, -> (category_ids) { 
  return unless category_ids.present?
  includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: category_ids })
                       .group(:id).having("count(*) = ? ", category_ids.size)
}
```